# What is so special about the Schwarz Inequality?

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, analysis, inequality

I am studying Spivak's Calculus and the first two problem sets have  rather lengthy,but very interesting, work-throughs of three proofs for the Schwarz Inequality:

$$\sum_{i=1}^{n} x_iy_i   \leq\sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^{n}x_{i}^{2}}\sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^{n}y_{i}^{2}}$$

Spivak calls this inequality the great-grandaddy of all inequalities, but leaves it at that. I, of course, consulted wikipedia [Schwarz Inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%E2%80%93Schwarz_inequality) which lists very technical explanations, but the page is listed as being incomplete an/or without proper references. Which leads me to ask, on a more basic level, what is so special about the Schwarz Inequality?

Comment: I recommend you have a look at [The Cauchy-Schwarz Master Class](http://www.amazon.com/The-Cauchy-Schwarz-Master-Class-Introduction/dp/052154677X). There you will find that "The typical chapter in this course is built around the solution of a small set of challenge problems. Sometimes a challenge problem is drawn from one of the world’s famous mathematical competitions, but more often a problem is chosen because it illustrates a mathematical technique of wide applicability." And that's the point - so many applications have their root in this one elegant inequality.

Comment: Often-times we like to work in [Normed Vector Spaces](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normed_vector_space) where we have a concept of "distance between things" that satisfies some basic properties, one of which being the [Triangle Inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangle_inequality), that $\|x+y\|\leq \|x\|+\|y\|$.  In order to prove that the triangle inequality holds in many contexts, the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality (or its generalizations such as [Holder's inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/H%C3%B6lder's_inequality)) is used.

Comment: You don't find it interesting that the inner product of two vectors is limited by the product of the two norms?

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, the Cauchy-Schwartz inequality is used to prove continuity of the inner product

Comment: It deals with square summable finite sequence in $\ell^2$ space, also the the continuous case deal with square integrable functions which is $L^2$. Both space are Hilbert spaces.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Cauchy-Schwarz inequality is indeed the Great-Grandaddy of all inequalities. Indeed consider this:

1. In **functional Analysis** in Hilbert Spaces, once you proved the CS inequality then you have the "Triangular Inequality" and the "Parallelogram Law", and then others minor inequalities which more or less are derived from them, such as Bessel's inequalities, etc...
2. In **Differential Geometry** since it's on the inner product it's at the very heart of the metric structure
3. In **linear Algebra** again since it is an inequality on inners product you can derive a lot of results from it.

So at the end I think Spivak is not at all overstating the Cauchy Schwarz inequality importance.